# Remote eIDAS Qualified Signatures: Control of Signature Activation Data

Tags: cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, eidas

In eIDAS Remote Qualified Signatures, but also in other Remote-Signature Solutions, the cryptographic keys are held by the Remote Signature Provider. The user uses some method, e.g., a smartphone app, to allow the creation of a signature.

How can the user be sure that the Provider and/or a malicious employee don't use the keys for unauthorized purposes? Is it solely based on trusting the Provider? Supposedly, the user holds the Signature Activation Data. Does the HSM of the Remote Signature Provider check, in a secure way, that the user initiated the signing?

Comment: In short: yes. For *qualified* signatures, they should be on a positive list of trusted providers anyway. And one should hope that they get on that list only after some serious auditing